# how would show value on screen

Tags: jquery, html

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLjS7.png)

Hi i want to create a comments section so when i input some text and click send then it will show what has been inputted down below. i wanted to know how i would implement. i'm new to this stuff.

customeVue.js

```
   $('#sendbutton').click(function() {
    var name = $('#comments').val();
 });
```

index.html

```
 <div id="commentSpace" class="form-group">
     <input type="text" id="comments" autocomplete="off">
     <button id ="sendbutton">send</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: In order to have an actual comment section that form needs to be submitted either the usual way or using `$.post` / `$.ajax` / `fetch()`, then your CI backend needs to add the user and comment into a comments database table, and when you display the page/article, you need to load and output associated comments.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set the innerHTML where you want to place the comment to the input.value

```js
var text="";
$('#sendbutton').click(function() {
    var name = $('#comments').val();
    
        text = text + name + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
        
        $('#comments').val("");
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="commentSpace" class="form-group">
     <input type="text" id="comments" autocomplete="off" />
     <button id ="sendbutton">send</button>
 </div>
 <div id='text'>
 </div>
```

Comment: I also have a view in codeIgniter with a session called : <h1 display="display-4"> <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?> </h1>. How would i get the session value in jquery and show it next to the inputted value

Comment: How would i add a new line everytime a message has been inputted i want to know how i could seperate it on to a new line

Comment: Hey bizz could you accept @DCR ‘s answer and create a new question for this please.

Comment: i'm using codeIgniter but i wanted to know how i could get a session which has a username stored to appear next to message. so i know who sent the message. i have the code for the session i would i add it in jquery as a html element

Comment: code updated to produce new line and clear input.  Accept answer if you want more help